# Adding a new table to EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are upgrading an old VB6 application which sits on a SQL Server 2005 database, to an Entity Framework solution. The database remains the same, except - we're adding a new table. Is it possible with Entity Framework, to maintain the existing structure, when it gets installed on a client PC - and just add one new table?

Is this how Code First will work? Can I be 100% certain that no other tables will be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think, the effort is worth it to switch to code-first if you have an existing database and want to add only one table.

it is possible to map code-first classes to an existing database (reverse engineer code first). actually, i'm not very experienced with that workflow, but i know you can. You have to deal with a lot of manual mapping (with DataAnnotations or Fluent API), so in your case i would recommend to use the Entity Framework Database First workflow, since adding a single table saves you a lot of work.

this link has some useful information: [Arthur Vickers Blog - Don't use Code first by mistake](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, use a database editor such as SQL management studio to create the table which you can then map to a ef entity, or use migrations for ef which will let you update your database via ef.

Take a look at the migrations tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621

Comment: can i ask why the down vote? perhaps i can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the **database first** approach, since a database developing team is doing the changes I require in the database on the SQL server for me.

Hence, I have to update the EDMX whenever the schema in the database changes.

**Note:** Changing one single table directly does not work for me, because VS doesn't always detect the changes right (for this issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13054212/1016343) are some details in SO if you're interested).

Hence, I am using the following workaround (regenerating all the tables):

1. In **VS 2012**, open the EDMX file by **double-clicking** on it. The graphic representation of the tables is shown.
2. **Left-Click** into the EDMX designer, then select all tables by pressing **CTRL+A**. Then, remove them by pressing **DEL**.
3. **Right-Click** into the EDMX designer and select **"Update Model from Database ..."** in the context menu.
4. The **Update Wizard** opens. In the **"Add" tab**, check **"Tables"**, and depending on the requirements, check **"Pluralize or singularize generated object names"**, **"Include foreign key columns in the model"** and optionally "Import selected stored procedures and functions into the entity model". Usually, I am using the "Pluralize..." and "Include foreign key columns..." options.
5. Click **Finish**. Now Save by pressing **Ctrl+S**.

That workaround works fine for me, and requires just a minute to update the model reliably.