# VS 2012 - EF 5.0 - Update Model from Database - Not picking up table changes

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010 EF 4, I could add a new column to a database table, then click 'Update Model from Database' on my .edmx and all was good in the world.

In Visual Studio 2012 EF 5, I alter a table, and then click 'Update Model from Database' and it does not pick up the changes to individual tables anymore.

Am I missing something ... or is this a new 'feature' of VS2012?

**Update**
The only way I can get a table with an added column to reflect in the .EDMX file is to delete the table then 'Update Model from Database' and it will pick up the added column. However, it puts the added table far off to the left and I have to move it back in place. No **biggie** just an annoyance.

Comment: This has always been quirky, even under 2010 and 2008.  Certain kinds of changes have never been propagated back to the model.  Perhaps this is one of those instances?

Comment: I hear ya, but at least it worked under 2010 to update a table and the edmx would pick it up. This takes me back to the LINQ days, where you have to delete the item then add it back in ... ugh

Comment: Like I said, it didn't always do that.  And you frequently did have to either update the object manually, or delete and re-add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between having an EF Model and how it is underlined in your database. When you "Update model from database", if the entity/table is already imported into your data model then you will be refreshing the entity. This process will not automatically map your database schema to your existing data model, you can however add a property to the entity in your EF model, and then map the property to the database column (this is exactly what EF does for you automatically when you delete and update normally).

When you delete the entity first, then update EF knows that the table/entity has not been imported before and so will map all of the database columns automatically for you.

In summary, you don't HAVE to delete the entity, but it can be easier to do so for simple entities.

Comment: I know, it's an annoyance to say the least. I guess it's because you could have made additional changes to the entity between when you added it, and when you refreshed it, but shouldn't that just be a hash check comparison? I'm sure the ADO.NET team have their reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this still works in VS2012. Are you using the default code generation or do you have a TT file? It could be that it's being added to the EDMX but your class files are not being updated.

Try right-clicking on the EDMX file or the relevant TT file in Solution Explorer and choose "Run Custom Tool" to make sure it's being regenerated.

Comment: That indeed rebuilds the classes and picks up changes to the .edmx file.

However, if I alter a table it still isn't picking up those changes. See here: [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/fahh6WqNYZ)

Comment: The table with the new columns won't show up under the "Add" tab; they'll be on the "Refresh" tab. Is your table listed under Refresh in that tab? Adding a new column to an existing table has *always* worked for me under 2010 and 2012. But yeah that putting it WAAAY off to one side is a new 2012 feature :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar/the same issue, and I deleted the table from the model, then chose "Update model from database." This again didn't work, and I couldn't access the new column that I added to the table.

However, once I manually checked out the model's designer file from source control (Vault Professional), and then deleted the table from the model and updated the model from database again, it worked. So maybe VS doesn't know to check out the model's designer file in this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

it is happend because you delete one of your entity and now want to update it from database again.the model is caching this enitities thats why you dont getting the choice to update the table.so you have to do right click on the model page and select model browser option.you will find model browser on the right side.delete the entity which you wnat to update from the entity type folder.now do whatever you want.